# How do I import from a `.d.ts` file?

Tags: angular, typescript

This line works in a project which uses angular2 RC4

`import * as mapTypes from '../../../../node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts';`

What's happening?

Now I am trying a new seed file with RC6 and the same line gives me this error

`error TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing '../../../../node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/services/google-maps-types' instead.`

But if I make the suggested change, I get

`Cannot find module '../../../../node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/services/google-maps-types'`

The `.d.ts` file looks like this:

```
/**
 * angular2-google-maps - Angular 2 components for Google Maps
 * @version v0.12.0
 * @link https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps#readme
 * @license MIT
 */
export declare var google: any;
export interface GoogleMap {
    constructor(el: HTMLElement, opts?: MapOptions): void;
    panTo(latLng: LatLng | LatLngLiteral): void;
    setZoom(zoom: number): void;
    addListener(eventName: string, fn: Function): void;
    getCenter(): LatLng;
    setCenter(latLng: LatLng | LatLngLiteral): void;
    getBounds(): LatLngBounds;
    getZoom(): number;
    setOptions(options: MapOptions): void;
}
...
```

and the matching `.ts` file looks like

```
/**
 * angular2-google-maps - Angular 2 components for Google Maps
 * @version v0.12.0
 * @link https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps#readme
 * @license MIT
 */
"use strict";

//# sourceMappingURL=google-maps-types.js.map
```

*NOTE*: There is a newer version of this package which is matched to RC6, but I should be able to get this to at least compile in TS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using last versions of TypeScript and the typing definition is embedded in your npm package, then you can just import from the module :

```
import { GoogleMap } from 'angular2-google-maps/core/services/google-maps-types'
```

Even if it's an interface.

In fact you're importing the definition from `core/services/googles-maps-types.js`, but this file exists only to provide definition associated in its `.d.ts` file.

It's been made to work as if you were importing directly from a `.ts` file, but as you're in an npm module, they embed definition file to permit definitions imports.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in TypeScript you would add a reference to the definition file at the top of your .ts file like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts"
```

After that you can import stuff that is in the definition file.